# xPages - adding a field down the track

Tags: xpages

I want to add a field to an existing xPage, and need to run past a few xPage fundamentals to check their validity.

I have done the following:

- In order to ensure that my dev and prod sites work, the form the document is bound to is calculated (as the datasource resides in a diff db).
- My new field is called 'NewField', and I have used simple data binding, chosen document1 (same as the rest of the fields on my document), and entered the new field name (can't select from the drop down as the document is calculated).
- I have also created the field on the actual notes document, however I did not think I HAD to do this?  Also, it's on a calculated subform so not sure if this is relevant?  This is an xpage version of an existing notes form - both client and web access are applicable for the application.
- I thought it would create the field specified in 'Bind To' if it was missing, however even with it on the notes form, it still does not store the value.

Whats gone wrong:

- The field is created on the document, however the value is not being populated.  The value stored against the notes document is an empty string.
- There is nothing complicated here, not doing anything funky, yet the value is not mapped?
- The rest of the fields (created when I created the initial document) are mapped correctly.

Any suggestions?  Is this a rookie error with adding fields to an existing xPage?

A

*As requested, here is the code for both the data binding and a field that does work, and one that does not.*

---

Here is my initial code to define *document1*.  It does call an agent post save, however this agent does nothing with the field value that is not being assigned.

```
<xp:this.data>
 <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument">
  <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var sname = ("","test\\testdb.nsf"); 
    return sname;}]]>
  </xp:this.databaseName>
  <xp:this.formName><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "MainForm"}]]>
  </xp:this.formName>
 <xp:this.postSaveDocument>
  <xp:executeScript>
   <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var sname = @Name([CN]",@Subset(@DbName(),1));
      var dbname = "test/testdb.nsf";
      var dbTest:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(sname, dbname);
      if (dbTest.isOpen()){
        ag = dbTest.getAgent("UpdateDoc"); 
        noteid = document1.getDocument().getNoteID(); 
        ag.run(noteid); 
          } }]]></xp:this.script>
   </xp:executeScript>
  </xp:this.postSaveDocument></xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

And then here is the code for the field assignment that is not working.

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.NewField}"
  id="inputText25" disableClientSideValidation="true" styleClass="entryboxes">
</xp:inputText>
```

And then here is the code for a field assignment that is working.

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.CLRef}"
  id="inputText4" rendered="#{javascript:@IsNewDoc()}" styleClass="entryboxes">
</xp:inputText>
```

I *thought* that this was fairly standard.

---

update 8/10

So - I have worked out that this happens only when I have conditionally hidden cell.  This has a basic formula, asking the row to be visible based on the value of another field.  The display / no display functionality is working (see below for code), yet, for a reason unknown to me, it does not save the value.

```
var hw = getComponent("module");
var hwv = hw2.getSubmittedValue();

hwv == "Product1" || hwv == "Product2" || hw2v == "Product3"
```

If I create any other field NOT hidden (and make up the field name), it maps to the document correctly (as I thought it should).  The good news is I have managed to replicate with a new form, so it appears to be with me wanting to hide a row conditionally, and not an issue with my form?  Any ideas?

Comment: Are there other fields on the XPage that are bound to the same Notes document that are getting updated?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have added the code here.  Hope it's too chunky now.

Comment: Try changing the action parameter on the document data source to "editDocument".

Comment: tried changing the 'editDocument' - no joy.  Have updated more info above.

Comment: I ended up making the field visible, and having a custom validation - only validating if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I continued to have issues with the field mapping when the cell was hidden in certain conditions.  So, I ended up making the cell visible, and then having the field mandatory only in certain circumstances.  So, question not answers, but a work around used.